# Arranging Seperate Strokes

Tags: grease-pencil

I have just started using 2d grease pencil and have been able to keep up with layers but now I want to animate and am running into a wall. I have a car driving through a landscape and when I keep it all in the same stroke its too difficult to select and move through the landscape, so I separated it into two strokes but now the car is behind the landscape. I know you can arrange sending stuff to the front and back but that's in the same stroke. I have two separate strokes, I want one to be in front of the other can I not do this? it seems like it should be easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you created two different Grease Pencil Objects, one for the car and one for the background.

To solve your depth problem simply move the car GP object in object mode slightly toward the camera (along Y axis in my example).

Another method is to give to all Layers an unique name, select both GP Objects in object mode, press Ctrl J to join them and lock all background layers, using the padlock icon in the layer stack, so to make them unselectable and unchangeable.
Then use the Layer stack order to determine the desired depth order, and the Arrange function to manage the strokes within each individual layer.

[image]